# Powershell popup to list of usernames

Tags: powershell

I wish to have a powershell script that provides a popup message to a specific list of users.  I need to use a list of relevant users in a spreadsheet with their network username and not use Active Directory.  I have the powershell script to display a suitable message with a Warning icon and found to format the popup in a certain way I had to use a "FORM" and not a default popup messagebox.  Although the following two lines for the Warning icon would not work in the form so had to use a picture box

```
$WarningIcon = New-Object ([System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning)
$Form.Controls.Add($WarningIcon)
```

The script for the form is as follows.  There is probably a cleaner way of creating a form like this but I am quite new to Powershell!

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Width = 700
$Form.Height = 400
$Form.BackColor = "#DCDCDC"

$Form.Text = "System Restart Alert"

$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Ariel",30, 
   [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold::Underline)
$FontB = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Ariel",14, 
   [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)

$Picture = (get-item ("C:\FA_Files\Windows_Warning_Exclamation9.jpg"))
$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($Picture)
$pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBox.Location = New-object System.Drawing.Size(160,30)
$pictureBox.Height = "100"
$pictureBox.Image = $img
$Form.controls.add($pictureBox)

$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Location = "260,30"
$Label.Font = $Font
$Label.ForeColor = "Red"
$Label.Text = "WARNING!"
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)

$LabelB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelB.Location = "100,130"
$LabelB.Font = $FontB
$LabelB.Text = "Due to essential maintenance system requires rebooting"
$LabelB.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelB)

$LabelC = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelC.Location = "100,160"
$LabelC.Font = $FontB
$LabelC.Text = "Please save all work immediately"
$LabelC.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelC)

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = "300,280"
$okButton.Font = "$FontB"
$okButton.Size = "85,28"
$okButton.Text = "Okay"

$Form.Controls.Add($okButton)
$okButton.Add_Click = ({$Form.Close()})
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

I can retrieve a list of network usernames from the spreadsheet okay.  Below is an image of the csv content

[image]

But I have googled a lot and cannot find a way of sending the popup to the list of usernames retrieved from the spreadsheet.  So far I have tried the following where I have the form above set to the $msg varaiable and also tried having the form in another file and referencing that file in the $msg variable but it doesn't work

```
$csv = Import-csv "C:\FA_Files\NetNames.csv"

foreach($line in $csv)
{
  $name = $line.("Name")
  $netName = $line.("NetworkName")
  #Echo "Name is $name and Network Name is $netName"
  msg $netName $msg
}
```

It also has to be on the username and not the machine name.

How do I correct this please?

Comment: SO is not a script writing service (something I expect someone with a reputation of 691 to know). Please provide at least a sample of your own work so far.

Comment: As above... edit your question and include your code, even if it doesn't work it gives us an idea of what you're trying to do! And shows you've put some effort in, not just expecting someone else to do it all for you. Once you include your code I'm sure you'll get some help with this :)

Comment: Show us what your user input list looks like **SANITIZE IT FIRST**, don't be the guy who leaks customer data on StackOverflow, and we'll see if we can help.

Comment: Check this, how to run a something on another computer : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/86a22984-b408-4b4b-9923-7a10aa6c4090/display-dialog-box-remotely-in-powershell-using-invokecommand?forum=ITCG

Comment: @bluuf Sorry, I have amended this now.  I was trying to avoid the question being long if I included all the work I had done so far.  I don't have that much experience in Powershell as yet

Comment: @JamesC. As above, I have amended this now.  I was trying to avoid the question being long if I included all the work I had done so far.  I don't have that much experience in Powershell as yet

Comment: @FoxDeploy I have amended the question and added a data example

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, `msg.exe` has replaced `net /send` in Windows, and is meant for sending messages to users, so I would begin by [looking at the syntax for message.exe here](https://ss64.com/nt/msg.html).  .

It has a `/server:` switch you can use to send a message to a remote host.  So, take your user and computer name list and put them in a CSV file like this:

```
//MyInputFile.csv
ComputerName,UserName
Laptop01,BillG
Laptop02,StephenO
PC03,WayneH
Desktop04,JimA
```

You could use a short script like this to achieve your goal (or get you mostly there, at least )

```
$Msg = "Put your message here"
$SpreadSheet = Import-CSV .\PathTo\MyInputFile.csv
ForEach ($row in $SpreadSheet){
    "Sending message to \\$($row.ComputerName)\$($row.UserName) : $msg"
    msg /server:$($row.ComputerName) $($row.UserName) $msg
}
```

You'll see an output like this in the console:

```
Sending message to \\Laptop01\BillG : Put your message here
Sending message to \\Laptop02\StephenO : Put your message here
Sending message to \\PC03\WayneH : Put your message here
Sending message to \\Desktop04\JimA : Put your message here
Sending message to \\localhost\* : Put your message here
```

Then your lucky user will see the following on their workstation.
[image]

If a computer can't be reached, the process will time out after five seconds or so and move on to the next one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

All users that are a member of Active Directory by default receive read rights, this is by design as Active Directory is exactly the kind of system that should be relied on for the kind of functionality you desire... not sure why your ICT manager is so against the idea.

You cannot send a message to a user (with only the username), you must know the machine the user is logged into as well.

The only way I can think to achieve this is to iterate through every computer and query who is logged on and if the user matches your list then send a message to that computer. This would require reading a list of computers from AD or iterating through every available IP address on your local network(s).

Comment: You can send a message with a user using the newer `msg.exe` utility, it takes both a servername and optional user name param, so you could use it to send a message to every user on a host, or a specific user on a specific host.

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasnt clearer, I should have said you can only send a message to a user if you know the computer they are logged into. OP doesnt have a list of computers, only users. The list becomes out dated as soon as a user changes their computer.